# Aged 0 to 30 days

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

Can any one please explain crystal reporting built in function Aged 0 to 30 days and how I can write this function in SQL (MSSQL). According to a link this function calculates from 30 days ago until today.  Please help.

Comment: FYI `Aged0to30Days` is not a function in Crystal Reports, but is merely a range of date values. For example, it can be used to test for inclusion `{Table.DateColumn} in Aged0to30Days`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
  Where dateColumn >= dateadd(day, -30, getdate())
```

Comment: This should work. It goes back 30 days from Today. 
have a look at this link for what exactly the Crystal Function does.
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/designer/Functions193.html

Answer (score 0):

What Rajesh use above should work. DateDiff function of sql. If you talk of writing a function like ask in the question. you can write a scalar function like below

```
 CREATE FUNCTION Aged0to30 (@DateValue datetime)
    RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @RangeValue AS int ;
      SET  @RangeValue = DATEDIFF ( Day , DateValue , getdate() )

      RETURN @RangeValue ;
    END;
    GO
```

To use in query just

```
Where  Aged0to30(dateColumn) <=30
```

There is a similar function addressing your question [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-functions-the-basics/).